# What happens when you create/edit a menu

Tags: plugin-development, menus, admin

I need to know this for a plugin I'm developing: What happens when a user creates a menu, add/remove menu items in the admin, what updates are made in the database, what  tables/columns are affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got into the database after trying this myself, so beware of inaccuracies. I'm also assuming the database-prefix is `wp_`.

What I found was that a refrence to the menu itself is stored  in both `wp_terms`and `wp_term_taxonomy`. The one in `term_taxonomy`also stores the number of elements in the menu.

The relationships between menu items and posts are stored in `wp_term_relationships` as refrences to post_id's and taxonomy_id's. I hope this was somewhat helpful.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That means I can programatically create a menu by inserting into wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy, which I did.